# How to get the last offset and loop through each page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

Iwant to get the list of all things to do in 'Canberra' from 'tripadvisor.com'.
Previously i used the same method for hotels and it worked fine , but now i have tried everything to get all things to do in 'Canberra' how does it fail?.
This my code for canberra things to do list:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen



offset = 0
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g255057-Activities-oa' + str(offset) + '-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#ATTRACTION_LIST_CONTENTS'
urls = []
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")


for link in soup.find_all('a', {'last'}):
    page_number = link.get('data-page-number')
    last_offset = int(page_number) * 30
    print('last offset:', last_offset)


for offset in range(0, last_offset, 30):
    print('--- page offset:', offset, '---')
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g255057-oa' + str(offset) + '-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#ATTRACTION_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
        iurl='https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255057' + link.get('href')
        print(iurl)
```

previously i used this code for hotels:

```
import requests
import re
import time
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

offset = 0
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g255057-oa' + str(offset) + '-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

urls = []
r=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")


for link in soup.find_all('a', {'last'}):
    page_number = link.get('data-page-number')
    last_offset = int(page_number) * 30
    print('last offset:', last_offset)


for offset in range(0, last_offset, 30):
    print('--- page offset:', offset, '---')
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g255057-oa' + str(offset) + '-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
        iurl='https://www.tripadvisor.com/' + link.get('href')
        print(iurl)
```

Comment: Please define "not working", how does it fail? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe ok i have edited :) thanks

Comment: Wait, I don't see any errors or tracebacks in the question body.